# How do I match the minimum of a subset in R, then do a lookup?

Tags: r, merge, aggregate, lookup

### Input

I have data broken down by customer and order, e.g.

```
Customer_ID Order_Source Date_of_order
1           Online       03/01/2017
1           Phone        02/01/2017
1           Store        01/01/2017
2           Fax          02/01/2017
2           Phone        01/01/2017
```

### Output

My aim is to:

1. Find the first order date (minimum) for each customer. Let's assume that each customer has one unique first order date (I have the times as well in case there is a tie for dates)
2. Then do a lookup to find the first order source used
3. Finally, create a new column with this information, i.e.

---

```
Customer_ID Order_Source Date_of_order   First_Order_Source
    1           Online       03/01/2017  Store
    1           Phone        02/01/2017  Store
    1           Store        01/01/2017  Store
    2           Fax          02/01/2017  Phone
    2           Phone        01/01/2017  Phone
```

My question is, **how do I lookup from the minimum of a subset like this?**

Comment: @989: Good point. I would've included my attempts, but I don't have the code on the machine I'm posting from I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a base R approach using `ave` to group by Customer:

```
df <- within(df, {
  Date_of_order <- as.Date(Date_of_order, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
  first_order <- Order_Source[ave(as.integer(Date_of_order), Customer_ID, FUN = which.min)]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this after grouping by 'Customer_ID', convert the 'Date_of_order' to `Date` class, get the index of minimum 'Date' (`which.min`), get the corresponding value of 'Order_Source' and `mutate` to create a new column.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Customer_ID) %>%
    mutate(First_Order_Source = Order_Source[which.min(as.Date(Date_of_order, "%m/%d/%Y"))])
#   Customer_ID Order_Source Date_of_order First_Order_Source    
#        <int>        <chr>         <chr>              <chr>
#1           1       Online    03/01/2017              Store
#2           1        Phone    02/01/2017              Store
#3           1        Store    01/01/2017              Store
#4           2          Fax    02/01/2017              Phone
#5           2        Phone    01/01/2017              Phone
```